# Simple arc/saggita/chord relation rearrangement

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, circles

I'm stuck with something that I feel should be trivial.

Consider the diagram on this page: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CircularSector.html

There are some pretty simple relations between the arc-length $s$, sagitta (arc-height) $h$ and chord length $a$, but all of them require knowledge of $R$, the radius of the arc, or of $\theta$, the central angle of the arc.

What I really want is, given only the sagitta and the arc-length, to find the chord length. I'm pretty sure this is possible.

Using the formula on the [Sagitta Wiki page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sagitta_%28geometry%29%20%22Sagitta%20Wiki%20Page) (which has different notation), we can eliminate R by writing it in terms of s and h. This brings us to:

\begin{equation}a/2 = R \sin(\theta/2) = R \sin (s/2R)\end{equation}

\begin{equation}R= \frac{h^2 + (a/2)^2}{ 2h}\end{equation}

\begin{equation}a = \frac{ h^2 + (a/2)^2 }{ h}    \sin( \frac{hs}{ h^2 + (a/2)^2 } )\end{equation}

but I can't rearrange this to have all the $a$'s on the left (i.e. $a=a(h,s)$ )

Can anyone help me?

---

Substituting $a=2A$ and rearranging gives the more direct:

\begin{equation} \frac{2Ah}{h^2+A^2} = \sin ( \frac{ hs}{h^2+A^2}) \end{equation}

Comment: Nice form ! You can still simplify using $A=x h$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your equations are correct, you face an equation in which appear algebraic expressions as well as trigonometric expressions  of the same variable $a$. It is not possible to obtain an explicit solution such as $a=f(h,s)$ as you wish. Numerical methods (they are simple) will solve the problem.

Comment: Thank you, yes. I've only now realised that in fact most functions *don't* have an analytic solution.